# Matrix Top list with aggregated remainders in Report Builder

Tags: sorting, matrix, reporting-services, filter, aggregate

I have had difficulties to sort this simple task out. I'll give you an example of what I would like to do. I want to create a top 5 list in a Report Builder matrix, and then I want to have the "left over" values aggregated and name them Other.

So far I have made a top 5 list within a group, added a new row and made a bottom list of the Other values. I'm not able to aggregate the Other values to one row. This is what I would like to have some help with.

The list could look like this:

Country Value

USA_____10

Canada__9

Mexico___8

Spain____7

France___6

Germany__5

Italy______4

Greece___3

Norway___2

Total_____54

And I would like to present the list like this:

Country Value

USA____10

Canada_9

Mexico__8

Spain___7

France__6

Other___14  *

Total____54

Answer (score 0):

Check this Sql Statement:
Customise your Query

```
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Points desc)ID,* into #Tmp from 
(select 'USA'Country,10 Points
union all
select 'Canada',9
union all
select 'Mexico',8
union all
select 'Spain',7
union all
select 'France',6
union all
select 'Germany',5
union all
select 'Italy',4
union all
select 'Greece',3
union all
select 'Norway',2)P

declare @min int=(select min(ID) from #Tmp),
@max int=(select min(ID)+4 from #Tmp)

--select * from #Tmp
select 
        Case when ID between @min and @max then Cast(ID as varchar)+' '+Country else 'Others' end Sort,
        Case when ID between @min and @max then Country else 'Others' end Country,
        Sum(Cast(Points as numeric(18,2)))Points 
from #Tmp
group by Case when ID between @min and @max then Cast(ID as varchar)+' '+Country else 'Others' end,
        Case when ID between @min and @max then Country else 'Others' end
order by Sort

drop table #Tmp
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, Thank you for your answer. It's a great solution, but not exactly what I was looking for unfortunately. I realized that I forgot to write that I'm using a Tabular Cube. In my Tablix I use several measures and based on one of them I want to create a top list and then group the left over values as Others in the category field. I hope it's more clear nor and that it makes sense. Thanks for your time. 
Br